# Grouping by week and product and summing over IDs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing amongst others the columns Product_ID, Producttype and a Timestamp. It looks roughly like this:

```
df
ID     Product     Time
C561   PX          2017-01-01 
                   00:00:00
T801   PT          2017-01-01
                   00:00:01
```

I already converted the Time column into the datetime format.
Now I would like to sum up the number of different IDs per Product in a particular week.
I already tried a for loop:

```
for data['Time'] in range(start='1/1/2017', end='8/1/2017'):
    data.groupby('Product')['ID'].sum()
```

But range requires an integer.

I also thought about using pd.Grouper with freq="1W" but then I don't know how to combine it with both Product and ID.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: in column `ID` are numbers? So need `data.groupby(['Product', pd.Grouper(freq='1W', key='Time')])['ID'].sum()` ?

Comment: Or need counts? `data.groupby(['Product', pd.Grouper(freq='1W', key='Time')])['ID'].size()` ?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah now I used data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Time", freq="1W"),pd.Grouper('Product')])['ID'].nunique()

Comment: So not working simplify your solution `data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1W', key='Time'), 'Product'])['ID'].nunique()` ? I think second Grouper is not necessary